# Comparing mean values by group between several variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, coefplot

I am trying to reproduce a graph from Stata in R. I have several variables and want to display their mean in each treatment group of which there are two. The Stata graph is as follows:

[image: coefplot trying to mimic]

This coefficient plot is not actually a plot of coefficients, but of the mean values by each treatment for each separate variable. The df basically looks something like.

[workable data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfm4gidcsii9902/collapsed_data_spending.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Ok so now we know what you want to do.  Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**.  Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out geom_pointrange() is probably what you are looking for:

```
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(111018)
interval1 <- -qnorm((1-0.9)/2)  

means_treatment_1 <- rnorm(2)
se_treatment_1 <- rnorm(2)

df_treatment_1 <- data.frame("Mean" = means_treatment_1,
                         "lower" = means_treatment_1 - se_treatment_1*interval1,
                         "upper" = means_treatment_1 + se_treatment_1*interval1,
                         "Variable" = c("medicare_spending_dummy", 
                                        "job_training_dummy"),
                         "Treatment" = "a")


means_treatment_2 <- rnorm(2)
se_treatment_2 <- rnorm(2)

df_treatment_2 <- data.frame("Mean" = means_treatment_2,
                         "lower" = means_treatment_2 - se_treatment_2*interval1,
                         "upper" = means_treatment_2 + se_treatment_2*interval1,
                         "Variable" = c("medicare_spending_dummy", 
                                        "job_training_dummy"),
                         "Treatment" = "b")



df_tot<-rbind(df_treatment_1, df_treatment_2)



# Plot


ggplot(df_tot, aes(colour = Treatment)) +
geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = gray(1/2), lty = 2) +
geom_pointrange(aes(x = Variable, y = Mean, ymin = lower, ymax = upper ),lwd = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 1/2)) +

coord_flip() + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*It is difficult to answer your question without reproducible data.*

---

However, this might get what you desire just with mean:

```
library(dplyr)
mpg %>% 
  select(manufacturer, cty, trans) %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer, trans) %>% 
  summarize(cty_mean = mean(cty)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cty_mean, y=reorder(manufacturer, cty_mean), color=trans)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

If you also wish to include the coefficients or std errors, then you could achieve by including a function in `summarize()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Here is a link to workable data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfm4gidcsii9902/collapsed_data_spending.csv?dl=0